# Flexbox adjust height of the img after div rotate

Tags: css, flexbox

Here is my codepen : https://codepen.io/Johngtrs/pen/oNWLYEw

When I click on the rotate button the div img container rotate, but the image overlap on the other row.

How it's possible to adjust the height of the img if needed ?

CSS:

```
.row-documents {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
.row-documents img {
    width: 615px;
}
.img-document {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.rotate-button {
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="row-documents">
    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <div class="row-documents">
    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: When I check this with the HTML Inspector (FF) I see that <div> `.img-document` gets transformed, not image `.img-responsive`. How do you (auto) resize `.img-document` so the image can fit?

Answer (score 2):

For the moment you cannot do this with Css only

you can check if your image is on the portrait format and change height of the parent when it is so

```js
$('.btn-rotate').on('click', function () {
  let $img = $(this).parent().prev();
  let width = $img.width();
  let height = $img.height();
  let angle = ($img.data('angle') + 90) || 90;
  let scale = height < width ? height / width : width / height;
  if (angle % 180) {
    $img.css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg) scale('+ scale +')'});
    $img.data('angle', angle);
  }
  else {
    $img.css({'transform': 'rotate(' + angle + 'deg) scale(1)'});
    $img.data('angle', angle);
  }
})
```

```css
.row-documents {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.row-documents img {
  max-width: 215px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.img-document {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transform-origin: center center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.rotate-button {
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="row-documents">
    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/740/1300" class="img-responsive">
    </div>

    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr />

  <div class="row-documents">
    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="img-document">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/1300/740" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <div class="rotate-button">
      <button class="btn btn-default btn-rotate">
        Rotate
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, ok I see I can't do that without JS. There is no adaptive layout for this. I think I'll try to modify the image height instead of row or both but I think I need to set a max-height for the row because if I receive large height image it will be dirty

Comment: I have a problem if the image start in portrait orientation. The image will overlap the button

Comment: I edited it to check if `$img.width() > $img.height()`

Comment: i don't think it's working, try with this image `https://picsum.photos/740/1500`

Comment: Oh yeah my bad I added a check for vertical img, check it and tell me if that suits your needs

Comment: I'll create another question because there are too many problems if we change the height of the row. I think I have to fix the image size on the first load to be safe

Comment: You can just change te height of the image it will adjst the parent height i edited so you can see

Comment: But I can't move the rotate button :/ I'm using the full container width, I create the new post https://stackoverflow.com/q/68319531/2519631 maybe it's clearer